# Export Rcpp modules

Tags: r, rcpp

I have built a package that exposes an Rcpp module. The relevant Rcpp code is here.

```
RCPP_MODULE(mod_dde) {
  using namespace Rcpp;
  class_<DdeConv>("DdeConv")
  .constructor<std::string, std::string>()
  .field_readonly("server", &DdeConv::_server)
  .field_readonly("topic", &DdeConv::_topic)
  .method("requestItem", &DdeConv::requestItem)
  ;
}
```

I want the package client to initialize an instance from this class with as few typing as possible.
In `zzz.R` I have the following code

```
loadModule("mod_dde", TRUE)
```

But when I try this

```
 d <- new(DdeConv, "EXCEL", "[DdeTest.xlsx]Sheet1")
```

I get

```
Error in .getClassFromCache(Class, where) : object 'DdeConv' not found
```

I have to do this

```
mod_dde <- Module(module = "mod_dde", PACKAGE = "rdde")
d <- new(mod_dde$DdeConv, "EXCEL", "[DdeTest.xlsx]Sheet1")
```

I know, it's not too much more typing, but I should be able to do the former per Dirk's excellent [vignette](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-modules.pdf)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps `export(DdeConv)` in your `NAMESPACE` ?

Comment: Thanks @RomainFrancois ! If you put it as an answer I'll accept it